# Using floating points such as f64 in your programs

Tags: math

What is the community take on doing fixed point arithmetic vs intermediary casting to `f64` to minimize precision loss? Recently I saw code using `f64` that got me wondering what the go-to way or standard way is for programs to deal with the loss due to integer division, and is `f64` the way to go in the future, or there are better ways out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was tempted to vote to close this as likely to elicit opinionated responses, but instead I'll post my opinion.

The trade off between fixed- and floating-point arithmetic is not precision loss, but rather *predictability* of precision loss.  It's pretty easy to reason about what your limitations are when you're working with fixed-point.  Floating-point on the other hand is a can of worms, what with its rounding modes, multiple zeros, infinities, Nans and subnormals all with quirks on when and how they can be used arithmetically.

Further, eBPF has no native hardware floating-point support, so you're going to get a slow soft-float implementation that's hard on the compute budget